# How can I run alias permanently in a normal way?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I have created an alias and appended to ~/.bashrc:

```bash
echo "alias mydir='cd /home/agochar/Desktop/folder'">>~/.bashrc
```

When I tried to run it like: `mydir` it says: `Command 'mydir' not found`
But when I  just run *.bashrc* like: `. ~/.bashrc` it works fine but not in a normal way.
Saying normal way I mean when we open terminal emulator it prompts: *username@hostname$* and we start typing commands. But what the heck is this:
`\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\033[;32m\]┌──(\[\033[1;34m\]\u㉿\h\[\033[;32m\])-[\[\033[0;1m\]\w\[\033[;32m\]]\n\[\033[;32m\]└─\[\033[1;34m\]$\[\033[0m\]`
When I type `mydir` it works.
The solution I want is I want `mydir` working without runing `. ~/.bashrc` each time I want it to use. Also to get rid of these *escape sequence like character* when I execute `. ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: If you don't want the alias to be created by sourcing your `~/.bashrc` file, why did you put it in your `~/.bashrc` file?  When you invoke a new `bash` process, it will automatically source your `~/.bashrc` file.  Are you saying that closing your terminal window and opening another (which invokes a new shell process) does not create your alias in the new window?  If it doesn't, are you perhaps using a different shell for your user account, one that doesn't read `bash` startup files like `~/.bashrc`?

Comment: It is not even creating alias in the same login session.  I am just the beginner and somewhere I have read that after creating alias you need to `. ~/.bashrc`(being new I am not too sure that what does it do?) but which I run `. ~/.bashrc` and just type command `mydir` it worked.  I am confused with those *\e \w \a* like character, wondering what just happened. And after while I close and open the terminal window again it is not working?

Comment: Sounds like your account in Linux is using a different shell that doesn't read the `~/.bashrc` that's specific to `bash`.  Please edit your question to include the output from this command: `ps $$`

Comment: It is unwise just to append to .bashrc. It is a script in its own right -- the standard one in my Mint is 125 lines. It has conditions, like an early return for non-interactive shells. It actually looks for (and uses) an alternative ~/.bash_aliases file, just so you don't have to hack the (sensitive) bashrc file, or re-add all your aliases when you install a new base version.

Comment: @SottoVoce The output of the command ==> ```1395 pts/0    Ss     0:00 /usr/bin/zsh```

Comment: @Paul_Pedant is there any way to know where my machine stores aliases permanently? I am very new in linux and trying to learn. Saying 125 lines, what do you mean ? Are you saying it reads the code or script only up to 125 lines or else?

Comment: Your account is using the `zsh` shell, which reads the file `~/.zshrc` when it starts, and does not read the file `~/.bashrc`.  The instructions you followed were written by someone who assumed everyone uses the `bash` shell, and you aren't.  That's why the command you put into the `~/.bashrc` was not being automatically invoked.

Comment: @SottoVoce so, Should I create aliases in ```~/.zshrc``` file? or can I make my system read ```~/.bashrc``` instead of another? (is it even possible?)

Comment: @AnupAdhikari give it a try.

Comment: @SottoVoce, It worked. Can I make my system read ```~/.bashrc``` instead of another? (is it even possible?)

Comment: You can change the shell that is invoked for your account to be `bash` instead of `zsh`, then your shell will read and use the `~/.bashrc` file.  You have a choice of putting the alias into the file that your current `zsh` shell uses, or change your account's configuration to the `bash` shell that will use the file you put the alias into.  I don't have an opinion on which is better.

Comment: is it possible to teach me here? or should I seek somewhere else?

Comment: @AnupAdhikari this write-up tells how you can change your shell (the write-up calls it your "default shell"):  https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-change-shell-to-bash/

Comment: Thanks a lot...